# how to get value of speific column in PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I used to here values from column with this code.

```
$con=new PDO("mysql:dbname=weLit","root","");
$sql="SELECT * FROM UserTable WHERE uEmail='aa@gmail.com' AND uPass='aabb'";
$arr=$con->query($sql);
$con=null;
foreach ($arr as $row){
$name=$row["uName"];
echo $name;
}
```

and i can get value from from specific column.

Now I use this code to prevent SQL Injection.

```
$con=new PDO("mysql:dbname=server","root","");
$stmt = $con->prepare("select uName from UserTable where uEmail=:email AND uPass=:pass") ;
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindParam(':pass', $pass);
$stmt->execute();
```

how to get value from specific column as above ?

please help ! I'm new to PHP.

And how to minimize the code as there will be always one row in result so i don't want to use foreach.

Comment: You need to fetch the result. (You also shouldn't store plain text passwords, hash them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `->fetch()` / `->fetchAll()` on the statement you just executed to get the data as an array or object.

It's pretty well documented:

- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-examples
- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetchall-examples

In your case it would look like:

```
$stmt->execute();
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $row){
  $name=$row["uName"];
  echo $name;
}
```